# Using pow() in C

Tags: c

I have this problem with this homework I'm supposed to do.

[ It says Create a program that's able to calculate and show the sum of **S**]

**Like S=1+1/4+1/8+1/16 ... till 1/ [2 pow n]**

So I worked on it and came up with this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int n,i;
float p,s;
printf("Enter the maximum power n :");
scanf("%d",&n);
s=0;
p=0;
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    p+=1/pow(2, i);
    s+=p;
    printf("s = %f\n",s);
}
printf("The sum of this equation is :%f",&s);
}
```

But when I execute it is always like S=0.
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean 1+1/4+1/8... or 1+ **1/2** +1/4+1/8... ?

Comment: No 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + 1/64 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing an address ('&s`) with`%f` variable. Using a wrong specifier invokes **undefined behavior**. You may get anything.

Also, No need of variable `s`. Remove the line

```
s+=p;
```

It should be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n,i;
    float p;
    printf("Enter the maximum power n :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p=0;
   for (i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       p+=1/pow(2, i);
       printf("p = %f\n",p);
   }
   printf("The sum of this equation is :%f",p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `<math.h>` to get the proper prototype of `pow()`.

You might need to link to the math library too `gcc main.c -Wall -lm`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <math.h>
....
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    p=1/pow(2, i);
    s+=p;
    printf("s = %f\n",s);
}
printf("The sum of this equation is :%f",s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program has multiple problems. Enabling compiler warnings should tell you about some of them.

1. You should include the C header which contains the declaration of the `pow` function.
2. You add each addend twice.
3. In your second `printf` statement, you pass a `float`. But the `%f` format specifier expects a `double` argument. In your third `printf` statement, you pass a pointer to a float.

Another cosmetic problem is that your `main` function should return an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

just a guess, may you replace the line

```
p+=1/pow(2, i);
```

with

```
p+=1.0f/(float)pow(2, i);
```

and

```
printf("The sum of this equation is :%f",&s);
```

with

```
printf("The sum of this equation is :%f",s);
```

Comment: The first change is unnecessary.

Comment: if he uses a standard compiler, yes.

Comment: Curious, what is the issue of the non-standard compiler that does not like `p+=1/pow(2, i);`?  Narrowing of `(double)` to `(float)`?

Answer (score 0):

Typo may be.. but you will have say `%f` and `s` (not `&s`)

```
printf("The sum of this equation is :%f",s);
```

On side note:

Once you include `<math.h>` you will get compiler warning for using correct `pow(..)` prototype. Below code would be relevant.

```
p+=1.0f/(float)pow(2.0f, i);
```